# Unable to Enable Virtualisation W10 Home

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization

I am a PC noob, but understand the benefits of having a VM set up. Thus, I am trying to set one up on my laptop. My specs are below (taken from System Information):

```
OS Name                        - Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version                        - 10.0.19042 Build 19042
Other OS Description           - Not Available
OS Manufacturer                - Microsoft Corporation
System Name                    - ***
System Manufacturer            - HP
System Model                   - HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15- cx0011ni
System Type                    - x64-based PC
System SKU                     - 4PP39EA#ACQ
Processor                      - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2208 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date              - Insyde F.25, 2020/11/13
SMBIOS Version                 - 3.0
Embedded Controller Version    - 70.60
BIOS Mode                      - UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer         - HP
BaseBoard Product              - 8478
BaseBoard Version              - 70.60
Platform Role                  - Mobile
Secure Boot State              - On
PCR7 Configuration             - Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory              - C:\WINDOWS
System Directory               - C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device                    - \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale                         - United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer     - Version = "10.0.19041.964"
User Name                      - ***
Time Zone                      - GMT Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM)    - 16,0 GB
Total Physical Memory              - 15,9 GB
Available Physical Memory          - 9,40 GB
Total Virtual Memory               - 18,3 GB
Available Virtual Memory           - 10,7 GB
Page File Space                    - 2,38 GB
Page File                          - C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection              - Off
Virtualization-based security      - Not enabled
Device Encryption Support          - Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions                    - Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   - Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware            - No
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection                     - Yes
```

I understand that W10 Home does not allow for Hyper-V, but that I should be able to run something like VirtualBox (which is my goal). I also understand that the first step in the process of getting VirtualBox up and running is to enable Virtualisation in the BIOS - where my problem lies.

I jump into the BIOS settings and enable virtualisation, but when I restart the laptop it goes straight into system recovery and is unable to restart, an endless cycle until I disable virtualisation. I have updated the BIOS etc. but still no luck.

Can anyone please assist with getting this up and running?

Comment: Turn off secure boot and try again. Also, enable virtualization in firmware. If you don't have an option in BIOS to enable virtualization then unless there is a BIOS update that introduces that feature, then its a no.

Comment: The important information here is "Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware - No".

Comment: Here for instructions on enabling virtualization depending on vendor - 

https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968

Comment: @Dean - Turning Secure Boot off will not solve this problem.

Comment: @harrymc - You cannot enable Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Home Single Language install.